# Ctrl+- (Ctrl+Hyphen-Minus) as ShortCut Key?

Tags: delphi, winapi, keyboard-shortcuts, zooming, keycode

It might seem natural to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> as shortcuts for an application's zoom in, zoom out, and restore default zoom (typically 100 %) actions. Now, in Delphi, I am able to assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> as shortcuts. The former, though, requires that the plus sign of the main part of the keyboard is used; the plus sign of the numerical keypad cannot be used.

Problem arises, however, when I want to assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> as a shortcut. It simply doesn't work. If I assign "Ctrl+-" in the IDE, the value stored in the `ShortCut` property is `16495`. If we subtract `ssCtrl` from this, we obtain 111. A work-around, one would believe, would be to assign `ShortCut := 45 + ssCtrl`, or, equivalently, `ShortCut := Menus.ShortCut(45, [ssCtrl])`, because `ord('-') = 45`. But that doesn't work.

However, I have found a working solution: `ShortCut := 189 + ssCtrl`. I choose 189 because that is the number I receive when I depress the "-" key and listen to the `KeyDown` event.

So, why am I not happy with this? Well, I am afraid that the constant 189 only is valid on *Swedish keyboards*. I have tried to read about this, and, as usual, [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646340(VS.85).aspx) is rather clear, but then, who knows how Delphi handles things.

Comment: Tip: add an alias for Ctrl+= for zoom in, otherwise you have to use Ctrl+Shift++ on keyboards without numeric keypads.

Comment: @Douglas: On my keyboard, I insert a plus sign by pressing the + key (no shift or ctrl+shift) right above "P" and "Å" (yes, Swedish keyboards do look like that - http://www.99.se/attachments/powerbook-macbook-pro/14819d1199736163-svenskt-vs-danskt-tangentbord-800px-kb_sweden.svg.png). This is also my issue: keys aren't the same on different keyboards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key code 189 is `VK_OEM_MINUS` in *Windows.pas*, so your solution isn't just for Swedes.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly what I wanted to hear!

Answer (score 1):

the correct to use menu shortcut on the numeric pad is
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Num +</kbd> for the [+]
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Num -</kbd> for the [-]

there is a space between Num +  and Num -

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting 16495 for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>.  When I add that shortcut to an action, it gives me 16573, and it does show up on the menu as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>, and that shortcut does work.

However, you are correct that `Menus.ShortCut(ord('-', [ssCtrl])` does not work. It gives the value 16429 and shows up on the menu as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Ins</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Ins</kbd> works as the shortcut.

Maybe this is a problem with Delphi 2009 and later since they added Unicode.

Comment: The `Word` type-cast is equivalent to the `Ord` function that he already tried.

Comment: Yes, but he doesn't want to hardcode the "45". Whereas this allows the character he wants. I'm not sure why he says it doesn't work on his machine. Either the "45" or the Word('-') both seem to work for me.

Comment: Oh, now I see his problem. The ShortCut function doesn't work. I'll have to change my answer.